# React setState of boolean value not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to React, trying to update the state of an object where on property already has a set boolean value. However, it seems like the state is not updating.

I understand that state is update asynchronously, maybe that could coming into play here? I don't believe I can use the setState method that takes an object and callback function because I need access the the previous state.

Here is my initial state:

```
items: [
    {
        id: 0,
        title: 'Dev Grub',
        selected: false
    },
    ...
]
```

And here is my event handler:

```
handleCardClick(id, card) {
    this.setState((preState, props) => ({
        [preState.items[id].selected]: [preState.items[id].selected] ? false : true
    }));

    console.log('new state: ', this.state.items[id].selected);

}
```

I've also tried this instead of the ternary: `![card.selected]`

Comment: `[preState.items[id].selected]:` should be `selected: ...` Try logging state and check for object you updated

Comment: You'll have to return an object that looks like this: `{items: [....]}` but instead, you're returning something like this: `{'true': false}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updating just a property at the second level of the state won't work. use something like below:

```
handleCardClick(id, card) {
    let items = [...state.items];
    items[id].selected = items[id].selected ? false : true
    this.setState(() => ({
        items
    }));
}
```

Comment: This worked, but I specifically liked that yo mentioned state can't be edited at the second level like I was doing. thank you

Answer (score 0):

React `setState` doesn't work this way, it doesn't update state right away but rather enqueues the change to update it at some point in the future.

If you want to do something as soon as the state has been updated you can use callback parameter

```
this.setState((preState, props) => ({
    [preState.items[id].selected]: [preState.items[id].selected] ? false : true
}), () => console.log('new state: ', this.state.items[id].selected);)
```

See [docs on setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Answer (score 0):

setState is async, you console log after the state has been changed like ths

```
handleCardClick = (id, card) => {
  this.setState(
    {
      [this.state.items[id].selected]: [this.state.items[id].selected]
        ? false
        : true,
    },
    () => console.log('new state: ', this.state.items[id].selected),
  );
};
```

Comment: I thought it was bad to refer to `this.state` while updating state and to use `setState(() => {})` approach?

Comment: you can access state when changing, example a toggle: 

``this.setState({show:!this.state.show}})``

Comment: I realize you can, the docs mention you shouldn't. I guess it's ok if you know how you're updating state elsewhere? https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: yes, you have to be careful. But it also depends in your implementation,